# Attempting to increment by 1 every time a class objects is used, but the count stays the same(JAVA)

Tags: java, object

I have to create a program that creates a scrabble tile. I have no problem creating the letter and value, but I need to have an id number for each tile and that's where the problem is. For my class objects I have:

```
char tile;
int value; 
private static int ID = 0;

//Default Constructor
public STile() {
    this.tile = '?';
    this.value = 0;
    STile.ID++;
}

//Constructor with parameters. 
public STile(char tile, int value) {
    this.tile = tile;
    this.value = value;
    STile.ID++;
}
```

And my getter for this is:

```
public static int getID() {
    return STile.ID;
}
```

The tiles are created fine but the ID of every tile is 26(the for loop to create them runs 26 times). So every letter should be a different number 1-26. I tried setting a variable equal to STile.ID and that didn't seem to work either, So I'm back to what I have up top.

EDIT:

So I retried setting it to a variable and it worked.

```
public LTile(){
    this.tile = '?';
    this.value = 0;
    count = LTile.ID;
    LTile.ID += 1;
}
public LTile(char tile, int value){
    this.tile = tile;
    this.value = value;
    count = LTile.ID;
    LTile.ID += 1;
```

Comment: *I tried setting a variable equal to STile.ID and that didn't seem to work either* - Post that attempt.

Comment: Why does each tile need a separate `id`?

Comment: Its just the parameters I was given. Personally I don't see the point.

Comment: And ok I just got it working it by retrying to set it equal to a variable. I can't seem to get the code to format so I'll edit the original.

Comment: For the record, you can still combine your two statements, for better or worse: `count = LTile.ID++`

Comment: You should reuse the parameterised constructor from the default one to avoid duplicating code - call `this('?',0)` in the body. The reason your first attempt failed is that static variables are global to the class and so all would see the last value, where instance variables are local to the object. But you probably worked that out.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe have two ID values, one static and one not, then after incrementing that static ID, set the objects ID equal to the static ID.

Comment: That actually did it. I had tried it prior but I must have messed up.

Comment: Yeah. Static means there's only one variable so you got all the values the same.

Comment: @user3769402 consider accepting the answer as a solution?